# Extracting a specific string out an HTML document

Tags: python, html, parsing

I need to sample and extract only a specific string out of an offline HTML document and write that information nice and clean into a *.txt file.

So for example, lets assume that this is a section of the HTML file:

```
    <span id="dataView01">001.00 SPL</span>
    <span id="dataView02">543.00 SPL</span>
    <span id="dataView03">056.00 SPL</span>
    <span id="dataView04">228.00 SPL</span>
```

I need to get this as a result:

```
   001.00 SPL
   543.00 SPL
   056.00 SPL
   228.00 SPL
```

Could you please help me with this,
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an HTML parser like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).
Example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re

markup = '''<span id="dataView01">001.00 SPL</span>
    <span id="dataView02">543.00 SPL</span>
    <span id="dataView03">056.00 SPL</span>
    <span id="dataView04">228.00 SPL</span>'''

soup = bs(markup)
tags = soup.find_all('span', id=re.compile(r'[dataView]\d+'))
for t in tags:  
    print(t.text)
```

Result:

```
001.00 SPL
543.00 SPL
056.00 SPL
228.00 SPL
```

---

Next step; write to .txt file:

```
import csv

with open('output.txt','wb') as fou:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(fou)
    for tag in tags:
        split_on_whitespace = t.text.split()
        csv_writer.writerow(split_on_whitespace)
```

Comment: Please note: code is for illustrative purposes, and there are certainly other ways to do this. If you have questions feel free to post a comment and I will explain ASAP. Best of luck.

Comment: Hello, just downloaded bs4, works great. The only part I am not sure about is how to sample the html file and get all the "<span id="dataView02">543.00 SPL</span>" strings ready to be processed by the bs4 library. Thanks! Really helpfull.

Comment: Have you tried the `.find_all()` code sample I posted? It is tailored to the markup example you provided.

Comment: Sorry, I have not seen it. I am a bit new to all of this stackoverflow posting and linking etc.

Comment: I got all of that working, the only missing part is the part where I open the HTML file and sample it, so that I can feed it into the bs processor. Thanks alot for the help!

Comment: For that have a look at `urllib2`; specifically `.urlopen()`. Here's a handy HOWTO on the subject: http://docs.python.org/howto/urllib2.html

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for keeping asking this, but will this work on an offline HTML file?

Comment: Yes, definitely. You can open it up as a plain-text file.

Comment: Great! Works! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

Comment: Thanks, I progressed with the bs4 answer above. bs4 works great.

Answer (score 0):

```
 import re
 s='001.00 SPL 543.00 SPL 056.00 SPL 228.00 SPL'
 print re.search(r'(\d{3}\.\d{2}\sSPL\s\d{3}\.\d{2}\sSPL\s\d{3}\.\d{2}\sSPL\s\d{3}\.\d{2}\sSPL)',s).group()
```

I dont know the surrounding text in the html document but this might work.

I see your edit i will update mine

actually go with jldupont's answer.

Comment: Thanks! Well, I am not familiar with the file operations :( I need to open the HTML file, then sample it only for those lines and then extract that middle part. The re lib probably will do the job of finding and then I will split and filter and extract but I am not sure how will I open the file and scan it. Thanks!