# How to use re.compile to search for strings with common areas in the middle

Tags: python, regex, string, beautifulsoup

I search for the following lines coming from a messy HTML file:

```
    <span id="fooPack1_xpl01_name11">150.00 FTL</span>
    <span id="fooPack1_xpl02_name11">350.00 FTL</span>
    <span id="fooPack1_xpl03_name11">250.00 FTL</span>
    <span id="fooPack1_xpl04_name11">230.00 FTL</span>
```

I use BeautifulSoup and re to search and find the strings:

```
     tags = soup.find_all('span', id=re.compile(r'[fooPack1_xpl04_name11]\d+'))
```

But obviously the common part of that string is at the beginning and at the end, with the part changing always in the middle. How can I restructure my re search pattern so that it searches for "fooPack1_xpl"+(different string)+"_name11"

Thanks.

// EDIT //

When I query the following:

```
    <span id="FullView1_spl02_Stack_4">03/04/12</span>
    <span id="FullView1_spl03_Stack_4">01/03/11</span>
    <span id="FullView1_spl04_Stack_4">02/25/02</span>
    <span id="FullView1_spl05_Stack_4">07/16/04</span>
    <span id="FullView1_spl01_Stack32">999.00 SPL</span>
    <span id="FullView1_spl02_Stack82">150.00 XPP</span>
    <span id="FullView1_spl03_Stack82">350.00 XPP</span>
    <span id="FullView1_spl04_Stack82">450.00 XPP</span>
    <span id="FullView1_spl05_Stack82">550.00 XPP</span>
    <span id="FullView1_spl06_Stack82">650.00 XPP</span>
    <span id="FullView1_spl07_Stack22">888.00 SPL</span>
    <span id="FullView1_spl202_stckFriendName">Red Car</span>
    <span id="FullView1_spl203_stckFriendName">Green Car</span>
    <span id="FullView1_spl204_stckFriendName">Blue Car</span>
```

with:

```
     foo=soup.findAll('span', id=re.compile(r'FullView1_spl\d+_stack82'))
```

I get the following result:

```
    <span id="FullView1_spl204_stckFriendName">Blue Car</span>
    <span id="FullView1_spl02_Stack82">150.00 XPP</span>
    <span id="FullView1_spl03_Stack82">350.00 XPP</span>
    <span id="FullView1_spl04_Stack82">450.00 XPP</span>
    <span id="FullView1_spl05_Stack82">550.00 XPP</span>
    <span id="FullView1_spl06_Stack82">650.00 XPP</span>
```

Obviously, I do not need the top element to be detected. So this is the only problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. You want to search for `fooPack1_xpl` followed by digits followd by `_name11`, so how about:

```
re.compile(r'fooPack1_xpl\d+_name11')
```

Note that I just put a `\d+` for where you expect the digits, and the literal string you were searching for otherwise.

Comment: Hello, I am trying to first find the lines that have those strings in the HTML file, and then extract only the "230.00 FTL" part. The original question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10019954/extracting-a-specific-string-out-an-html-document But by changing the re.compile section, it does not seem like I am getting the right lines :(

Comment: What is the point of asking this question when you have already asked a duplicate question back there? I have answered the specific question you asked, that is, how to match 'fooPack1_xpl' + digits + '_name11'. Details on how to extract are already given in the answer to your previous question.

Comment: Sorry. I just did not want to make that other topic too busy. Meanwhile I had a chance to get more information about the regex library.

Comment: Actually, ignore me, I think it works. I am getting what I need with that pattern. Thanks for the help.